# И вновь про mysql и кириллицу

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка

Имеется БД с параметрами:

```
| character_set_client                    | latin1                                                                                    
| character_set_connection                | latin1                                                                                    
| character_set_database                  | latin1                                                                                    
| character_set_filesystem                | binary                                                                                    
| character_set_results                   | latin1                                                                                    
| character_set_server                    | latin1                                                                                    
| character_set_system                    | utf8                                                                                                                                                  
| collation_connection                    | latin1_swedish_ci                                                                         
| collation_database                      | latin1_swedish_ci                                                                         
| collation_server                        | latin1_swedish_ci
```

Добавляю в эту БД таблицу с параметром `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

Далее делаю вставку записей в эту таблицу с кириллическими значениями.

Пробовал перед созданием таблицы, либо вставкой делать:

```
SET NAMES utf8
SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
SET CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Все без толку, вместо кириллицы вставляются '?'

Что еще можно сделать, чтобы кириллица вставлялась корректно?

Настройки БД менять не вариант, т.к. пишу плагин для уже существующей системы.

Comment: Из клиента строки в cp1251 приходят?

Comment: @vp_arth файл с текстом запроса в utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исследовал вопрос.
Установил phpMyAdmin. Даже при вставке русского текста в таблицу через веб-интерфейс (при этом таблица в utf8, бд в latin1) в итоге вместо кириллицы отображаются вопросы.

В общем, выход один - переконвертация кодировки бд в utf8.

Для справки - плагин разрабатывается для FreePBX. БД FreePBX создает автоматически при установке, полагаю.

Answer (score 0):

Рассмотрите такого рода вариант.Надеюсь поможет=)

```
class DB
{
private static $db;

private function __construct(){}

public static function getConnection() {
    if (self::$db === null){
        self::$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','db_name');
        self::$db ->query("SET CHARSET utf8");
    }
    return self::$db;
}
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но к сожалению, у Вас используется тот же способ, что и приведенный выше. Не помогло, разбираюсь дальше.